# HTML Email : Images go beyond its limited width in outlook

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have these images. they work fine in **Gmail** , but when I see in outlook , then all the 5 images comes in single `<tr>` and extends the default width of table.

What I want is , first **four** images should be in the center of first line and if there are more images then , it should be in new line. but in the same `<tr>`. I don't want separate `<tr>`for the same. I have done this. It looks fine in Gmail. but it extends its width in outlook which I have to make them correct. I have read article regarding the same. but didn't get too much.

So , It would be great , If I get help for this issue.

Thank You.

```html
<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="  background: #fa4b00;margin: 0 auto !important; padding: 0px; max-width:600px !important; line-height: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; text-align: center;" >


                    <tr>
                        <td height="20"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td style="vertical-align:top;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center;">
                            <img style=" outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg" border="0" height="120" width="120" >
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:10px;word-break: normal; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 600; ">XYZ</p>
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:8px;word-break: normal;  text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding:0px 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: white; "> XYZ </p>
                        </td>


                        <td style="vertical-align:top;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center;">
                            <img style=" outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" border="0" height="120" width="120" >
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center;  font-size:10px;word-break: normal ; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 600;">XYZ</p>
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:8px; word-break: normal ; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding:0px 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #FFFFFF;"> XYZ </p>

                        </td>


                        <td style="vertical-align:top;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center;">

                            <img style=" outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455627060.jpeg" border="0" height="120" width="120" >
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:10px;word-break: normal; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 600;">XYZ</p>
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:8px;word-break: normal;  text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding:0px 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #FFFFFF;">XYZ  </p>
                        </td>




                        <td style="vertical-align:top;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center;">
                            <img style=" outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg" border="0" height="120" width="120" >
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:10px;word-break:normal; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 600;">XYZ</p>
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:8px;word-break: normal;  text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding:0px 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #FFFFFF;"> XYZ </p>

                            <p style="padding-bottom: 30px;"></p>

                        </td>



                        <td style="vertical-align:top;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center;">
                            <img style=" outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455300140.jpeg" border="0" height="120" width="120" >
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:10px;word-break:normal; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 600;">XYZ</p>
                            <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:8px;word-break: normal;  text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding:0px 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0 auto; color: #FFFFFF;"> XYZ </p>

                            <p style="padding-bottom: 30px;"></p>

                        </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Try using CSS properties instead of `width="##" height="##"`

Comment: i have not given `height` to `table` and also I have given `max-width` property to table using CSS properties. :)

Comment: You have `height="120" width="120"` on every image

Comment: oh yaa.. got it.. trying to change them and check if it works or not.. thank you...

Comment: @Justinas... Not working in outlook. tried and checked , too

Comment: Is there some reason you're using a table in the first place?

Comment: I have header named **speaker**. i have put it in main `table > tr > td`. and for the speakers' names and images i have taken separate tr and in that i have taken a new table.

Comment: What exactly do you need the functionality to be? Do you want each cell to flow to the next line when the table isn't wide enough? (Which is how it works with your code.) Or do you want specifically the first 4 cells to be on one line and the rest on a second line?

Comment: I want 4 images to be in one line in main table having width of 600 and then if there are more images then they might be in the center of next line. suppose there are 2 images then 2 images must be on the center of 2nd line. ie. 4 images in one line having equal spacing and 2 images on the second line to be center of next line.

Comment: Could you just have two `<tr>`s?

Comment: i would have . but the problem would be if i remove one of the images from 1st line , then there would be 3 images and rest would be in next line. so instead of it , I would like to have that if i remove one of the image from 1st line then the 1st image of new line would take place to the 1st line of last image. just like queue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122491/discussion-between-user123-and-whothehellisthat).

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the TDs to `display:inline-block`, which doesn't really make much sense for a table element. The whole point of a table cell is that it behaves like a table cell.

Maybe that's what the issue is; if you're using an Outlook app or whatever it'll have a different rendering engine to Chrome. So that rendering engine could decide to ignore `display:inline-block` on table cells.

I'm pretty sure if you just removed the table stuff and wrapped each image in a DIV instead it would work reliably.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd5qwx20/)

Comment: I cant' use `div` . Here is the reason : [https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/05/div-tags-in-html-email-newsletters/]

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/05/div-tags-in-html-email-newsletters/

Comment: Okay. Looks to me like the issue is that the client doesn't like a number of style properties--like `display:block` for divs. But that also means it probably won't like `display:inline-block` either.

Comment: When you change the `display` property, the rendering engine changes how that element is seen. So stick a `display:block` on an element, and the renderer will kinda see it as a DIV, letting it behave and interact with content flow and so on as if it were a DIV.

Comment: yes.. that is i have removed, too. so is there any common solution for the issue that works fine for every email clients?

Comment: So if the renderer can't figure out how to display DIVs correctly, then it probably won't be able to display `display:inline-block` correctly either (it's kind of a half-DIV).

Comment: Here I was just trying to get your code working ;P...  I've commented on the main post. We need to get to the bottom of what you actually need.

Comment: i have given my need :)